# i want to search a string from the json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, object, search

I want to search the House Name from all the input the user provided.
so if the user details are as:

[{"houseName":"man","houseType":"villa","houseFloors":"seven","houselocation":"Seattle"},{"houseName":"band","houseType":"small","houseFloors":"two","houselocation":"washington DC"}]

If i provide search as man ,it should give me as:

[{"houseName":"man","houseType":"villa","houseFloors":"seven","houselocation":"Seattle"}]

The code is as :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>House Name
  <input type='text' name='houseName' id='houseName' placeholder="House Name">
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label>House type
  <input type='text' name='houseType' id='houseType' placeholder="House type">
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label>House Floors:
  <input type='text' name='houseFloors' id='houseFloors' placeholder="House Floors">
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label>House Location:
  <input type='text' name='houselocation' id='houselocation' placeholder="House Location">
</label>
<br>
<br>
<div>
<label>search:
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search-input" placeholder="search">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
<button type="button" id="add">Add Details</button>
<button type="button" id="print">Show</button>

<pre></pre>
<script>
    var list = [],
  $ins = $('#houseName, #houseType, #houseFloors, #houselocation'),
  var counter = {
    houseName: {},
    houseType: {},
    houseFloors: {},
    houselocation: {}
  };

 $('#add').click(function() {
  var obj = {},
    valid = true;
  $ins.each(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if (val) {
      obj[this.id] = val;
    } else {

      alert(" Cannot be blank");

      return false;
    }
  });
  if (valid) {
    list.push(obj);
    $ins.val('');

  }
});

$('#print').click(function() {
  $('pre').text(JSON.stringify(list) + '\n\n');

})
var keyword = $('#search-input').val();
var filteredList = list.filter(function(user){
   return user.houseName === 'man'; // Or u can use indexOf if u want check if the keyword is contained
});


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `Array.prototype.filter`.

In ur case it will look like

```
var filteredList = list.filter(function(user){
   return user.houseName === 'man'; // Or u can use indexOf if u want check if the keyword is contained
});
```

If u would like to search it with an input box, there will be a little bit more work to do:

```
//The follow code should be executed when u are going to do the 'search' action
//It could be an click on a button, or just in a listener which is triggered when the search box fires 'change' events

//First u need to get the keyword from the search input box:
var keyword = $('#search-input').val();

//maybe do some value check
//if (keyword === '') return;

//then get the filtered List
var filteredList = list.filter(function(user){
   return user.houseName === keyword; 
});

//Finally update the UI based on the filtered List
//Maybe jQuery's DOM functions could be helpful
```

Comment: If i create a search box field and if it searches for man then how should it look like.

Comment: @gaan10 – Contributors are not here to spoon feed.... Do some research about provided solution.. Also note that provided code contains error...

Comment: the above code is not working.i created a search box and tried to take the keyword from there.